# Language codes in platform SDK 6.1

Tags: c++, sdk

Language codes are in the form `"en-US`","`de-DE`" or "`sl-SI`" for `English US`, `German` and `slovakian` respectively. Whether there is any `#define` s present in `PLATFORM SDK 6.1` for language codes. Its better if i got these values instead of using Hard coded strings in my program. Can anyone help me regarding this. Its better if i get the header file name to include.
Thanks
Santhosh

Comment: I have a application which loads language specific dlls. I am using "GetUserDefaultLocaleName()" API for getting the user locale. This is returning values in the above said Format. What i can do in that case. Plz Help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no # defines present for language codes. We can use the function LocaleNameToLCID() to get the language ID for given language code.

Thanks all for help!!

Answer (score 2):

No. There are no defined strings - you are supposed to use string literals for these.

Comment: I have a application which loads language specific dlls. I am using "GetUserDefaultLocaleName()" API for getting the user locale. This is returning values in the above said Format. What i can do in that case. Plz Help!!

Answer (score 1):

You could use GetUserDefaultLCID() instead.  That's a number, you can compare it with the value produced by the MAKELCID macro.

Comment: This API is deprecated in OS Windows Vista and Above.. I need the API in OS's Windows Vista and above!!

Comment: You already found it, I thought you didn't like it.  No, there are no usable #defines in the SDK.